# How do I use a non-standard ceph system user?

Tags: ceph

I configured a ceph user on my cluster named "cepher." I ran ceph-deploy as this user to deploy some servers.

Then I see this:

[block][INFO  ] Running command: sudo ceph --cluster ceph --name client.bootstrap-mds --keyring /var/lib/ceph/bootstrap-mds/ceph.keyring auth get-or-create mds.block.ohoh.yo osd allow rwx mds allow mon allow profile mds -o /var/lib/ceph/mds/ceph-block.ohoh.yo/keyring

How can I make ceph-deploy use my cepher user?

Comment: Also, I don't want my cluster name to be "ceph." Can ceph-deploy use "ohoh" as a cluster name?

Comment: The docs say I can run
ceph-deploy --cluster {cluster-name} new {host [host], ...}
but this fails. I have the mimic repo installed.